# How to get incident details on email?

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-sentinel

Here is the playbook below:

[image]

My email:

[image]

I have ran my playbook successfully  and i recieve an email however i am unable to get details of the incident.

I am trying to implement A recurring playbook that triggers at knock-off hour every day (Mon-Friday), The paybook collects infomation about incident id , name , description , url. All the incidends assigned to the analyst, projected on a HTML table and send it to one of my colleagues. Does anyone have any tips on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reproducing from my end using the same flow as yours, I got the results as expected. Looking at your flow I can see that you are trying to set a variable which isn't a valid JSON. For creating HTML table you can make use of `Create HTML table` action .So, make sure you are framing it into a valid one as below.

Below is the flow of my logic app.

[image]

[image]

[image]

##### Results:

[image]

[image]